# Working with strings in java : extract a particular string

Tags: java, string

How to get the a particular part of string without using any index.
my string is like :

```
String path = "D:\SMPPPushGW_SMSCID1_Passive\note.bat";
```

from the above string, i want to extract

```
D:\SMPPPushGW_SMSCID1_Passive\
```

Can any one provide the code??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include the *code* what you've tried so far.

Comment: No they cant. What do you want? The last non space separated chunk in the string? The 4th non space separated chunk? The first chunk starting with D? The first chunk that contains an underscore? or 3Ps?

Comment: Where is your code???

Comment: Hai every one.. My requirement changed, kindly go through again.                                .............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

First make 'path' a StringBuffer to make it easier to work with. Then use indexes:

```
StringBuffer path = new StringBuffer("cmd /c start D:\\SMPPPushGW_SMSCID1_Passive\\note.bat");
String result = path.substring(path.indexOf("start")+5, path.lastIndexOf("\\"));
```

As mentioned, File API may be useful, but also URI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the path of the file then you can use java File api's

```
String path = "D:\SMPPPushGW_SMSCID1_Passive\note.bat";

File file = new File(path);
System.out.println(file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());
```